# Send a multidimensional array encoded in json to php and decode it

Tags: java, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Hi I'm writing a program in java and I created this array:

```
 String[][] ArrayString = new String[1000][7];
```

I need to send the populated array to mysite.com/json.php.
Then it must be decoded for remake the same array in php.

How can I create and send the array in a json post to the php in a mode that in php I can simply json_decode it and read the original java array in php?

Thanks, and I have already read similar questions here but with them I failed, because I need both parts operations and my array is big.

Comment: What is "bot part operations"? There are certainly duplicates for each part of this question (encoding java arrays as json, sending an HTTP request from java, decoding JSON with PHP)

Comment: @CollinD yes i intende a easy way for encode and decode, in other Questions was not clear how the json post resulted in php.